# How to save array of json object in postgres using typeorm

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to save an array of object in jsonb type in postgres

**Entity**

```
@Column({type: 'jsonb', array: true, nullable: true})
testJson: object[];
```

The json I am sending in postman

```
{
    
    "testJson": [
        {"skill": "docker", "experience": true},
        {"skill": "kubernetes", "experience": false}
    ]
}
```

I am getting error 'malformed array literal:'

Also kindly tell if I can query such data types?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same problem. This worked for me

```
@Column('jsonb', {nullable: true})
testJson?: object[];
```

Answer (score 4):

Above answer is helpful.
But it needs some update.
Following code worked for me in nest.js.

```
interface dataType {
  key: number;
  asset: string;
  owner: string;
  value: string;
}

@Entity()
export class Will {
  @Column({
    type: "json",
    nullable: true,
    transformer: {
      to(value: dataType[]): string {
        return JSON.stringify(value);
      },
      from(value: string): dataType[] {
        return JSON.parse(value);
      },
    },
  })
  dataOutSideWill?: dataType[];
}
```

Comment: Quick question, why are you doing the transformation here, wouldn't that slow down the time it takes to fetch the data in terms of complex queries?